# How do I make a div automatically wide enough to accommodate its floating children?

Tags: html, css, css-float, word-wrap

How do I make a div automatically wide enough to accomodate its floating children?

```
<div class="Parent"> <!-- 3 Children, should be 450px wide-->
  <div class="Child"></div>
  <div class="Child"></div>
  <div class="Child"></div>
</div>
<div class="Parent"> <!-- 2 children, should be 300px wide-->
  <div class="Child"></div>
  <div class="Child"></div>
</div>
```

The Child divs are all "float:left" with fixed widths. How do I make the Parent div be equal to the width of it's floating children? The number of children in each parent varies and is unknown but the children must line up in a row, without wrapping to a new line.

Example: If all three children are 150px, the parent should become 450px so that none of the children wrap. If there are two 150px children, the parent should become 300px.

Here's a demo of the problem:

```css
#MainNavBar {
    background:url('../assets/design/images/MainNavGrad.jpg') repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height:43px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}


.NavSpace {
   background:url('../assets/design/images/NavSpacer.jpg');
   float:left;
   width:2px;
   height:100%;
}



/*------------------------------------*\
   NAV
\*------------------------------------*/
#nav{
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   list-style:none;
   font-weight:bold;
   margin-bottom:10px;
}
#nav li{
   float:left;
   margin-right:10px;
   position:relative;
   display:block;
}

a.MainNavButton{ /*Main Buttons */
   text-transform:uppercase;
   font-family:verdana;
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:11px;
   text-align:center;
   text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); /* Text shadow to lift it a little */
   color:#fff;  
   display:block;
   padding:12px 21px 16px 21px ; /* TOP LEFT Bottom RIGHT */     
   -moz-border-radius:2px;
   -webkit-border-radius:2px;
   border-radius:2px;
}

#nav li a:hover{
   color:#fff;
   background:#444444;  /* Solid colour fall-back */
   text-decoration:underline;
}

/*--- DROPDOWN ---*/

/*
 * <div class="SubNavWrapper">
   <div class="SubNav">
      <div class="SubNavSectionWrapper">
         <h5>List 1</h5>
         <ul class="SubNavSectionList">
            <li><a href="#">The product</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Meet the team</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="SubNavSectionWrapper">
         <h5>List 2</h5>
         <ul class="SubNavSectionList">
            <li><a href="#">The product</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Meet the team</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div><!-- END Nav Pad-->
*/


div.SubNavWrapper {   
   float:left;
   padding:30px;
   padding-top:0px;
   position:absolute;
   background:transparent;
   left:-9999px; /* Hide off-screen when not needed (this is more accessible than display:none;) */
}

div.SubNav {
   float:left;
   clear:both;
   padding:30px;
   border:1px solid #222;
   border-top:none;
   background:#444;
}

div.SubNavSectionWrapper {   
   float:left;
   width:150px;
   height:200px;
   margin-right:45px;
}

div.SubNavSectionTitle { /* Title of a sub-section */
text-transform:uppercase;
font-family:verdana;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:11px;
padding-bottom:3px;
margin-bottom:3px;
border-bottom:1px solid #333;
color:#fff;  
}

ul.SubNavSectionList {
   list-style:none;
}

ul.SubNavSectionList li{
   padding-top:1px; /* Introducing a padding between the li and the a give the illusion spaced items */
}

ul.SubNavSectionList li a { /* Sub Menu Links */
font-family:verdana;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:11px;
color:#fff;
padding:4px 0px;
}

ul.SubNavSectionList a{
   white-space:nowrap; /* Stop text wrapping and creating multi-line dropdown items */
   display:block;
}

#nav li:hover div.SubNavWrapper{ /* Display the dropdown on hover */
   left:-30px; /* Bring back on-screen when needed */ /* must match SubNavWrapper!! */
   opacity:1; /* Fade to opaque */
}

#nav li:hover a{ /* Set styles for top level when dropdown is hovered */
   background:#444444; /* Solid colour fall-back */
   text-decoration:underline;
}

#nav li:hover ul.SubNavSectionList a{ /* Override some top level styles when dropdown is hovered */
   text-decoration:none;
}

#nav li:hover ul.SubNavSectionList li a:hover{ /* Set styles for dropdown when items are hovered */
   background:#333; /* Solid colour fall-back */
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="MainNavBar">         
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
       <a class="MainNavButton" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>    
    <li><!-- Animals Menu -->
       <a class="MainNavButton" href="#">Animals</a><!-- hover over me to show the "animals" menu -->
       <div class="SubNavWrapper"> <!-- This is a wrapper that is absolutly positioned off the screen, until
                                             the "animals" link is hovered over -->                  
          <div class="SubNav"><!-- This is a parent with floating children -->
              <!-- this is a child that floats left -->
              <div class="SubNavSectionWrapper">                        
                <div class="SubNavSectionTitle">Fish</div>
                <ul class="SubNavSectionList">
                   <li><a href="#">Gold Fish</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Barracuda</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
             <!-- this is a child that floats left -->
             <div class="SubNavSectionWrapper">
                <div class="SubNavSectionTitle">Reptiles</div>
                <ul class="SubNavSectionList">
                   <li><a href="#">Lizzards</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Snakes</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Iguanas</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
             
             <!-- this is a child that floats left -->
             <div class="SubNavSectionWrapper">
                <div class="SubNavSectionTitle">Birds</div>
                <ul class="SubNavSectionList">
                   <li><a href="#">Parakeets</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>              
          </div><!-- END SubNav -->
       </div><!-- END SubNavWrapper -->
    </li><!-- END Animals Menu -->
</ul>  
</div> <!-- END Nav Bar -->
```

When you hover over animals, you can see that birds, reptiles and fish are stacked on top of each other. They should show side by side.

This is what I want it to look like:

```css
#MainNavBar {
   background:url('../assets/design/images/MainNavGrad.jpg') repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
   height:43px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
}


.NavSpace {
   background:url('../assets/design/images/NavSpacer.jpg');
   float:left;
   width:2px;
   height:100%;
}



/*------------------------------------*\
   NAV
\*------------------------------------*/
#nav{
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   list-style:none;
   font-weight:bold;
   margin-bottom:10px;
}
#nav li{
   float:left;
   margin-right:10px;
   position:relative;
   display:block;
}

a.MainNavButton{ /*Main Buttons */
   text-transform:uppercase;
   font-family:verdana;
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:11px;
   text-align:center;
   text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); /* Text shadow to lift it a little */
   color:#fff;  
   display:block;
   padding:12px 21px 16px 21px ; /* TOP LEFT Bottom RIGHT */     
   -moz-border-radius:2px;
   -webkit-border-radius:2px;
   border-radius:2px;
}

#nav li a:hover{
   color:#fff;
   background:#444444;  /* Solid colour fall-back */
   text-decoration:underline;
}

/*--- DROPDOWN ---*/

/*
 * <div class="SubNavWrapper">
   <div class="SubNav">
      <div class="SubNavSectionWrapper">
         <h5>List 1</h5>
         <ul class="SubNavSectionList">
            <li><a href="#">The product</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Meet the team</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="SubNavSectionWrapper">
         <h5>List 2</h5>
         <ul class="SubNavSectionList">
            <li><a href="#">The product</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Meet the team</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div><!-- END Nav Pad-->
*/


div.SubNavWrapper {   
   float:left;
   padding:30px;
   padding-top:0px;
   position:absolute;
   background:transparent;
   left:-9999px; /* Hide off-screen when not needed (this is more accessible than display:none;) */
}

div.SubNav {
   float:left;
   clear:both;
   width:600px;
   padding:30px;
   border:1px solid #222;
   border-top:none;
   background:#444;
}

div.SubNavSectionWrapper {   
   float:left;
   width:150px;
   height:200px;
   margin-right:45px;
}

div.SubNavSectionTitle { /* Title of a sub-section */
text-transform:uppercase;
font-family:verdana;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:11px;
padding-bottom:3px;
margin-bottom:3px;
border-bottom:1px solid #333;
color:#fff;  
}

ul.SubNavSectionList {
   list-style:none;
}

ul.SubNavSectionList li{
   padding-top:1px; /* Introducing a padding between the li and the a give the illusion spaced items */
}

ul.SubNavSectionList li a { /* Sub Menu Links */
font-family:verdana;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:11px;
color:#fff;
padding:4px 0px;
}

ul.SubNavSectionList a{
   white-space:nowrap; /* Stop text wrapping and creating multi-line dropdown items */
   display:block;
}

#nav li:hover div.SubNavWrapper{ /* Display the dropdown on hover */
   left:-30px; /* Bring back on-screen when needed */ /* must match SubNavWrapper!! */
   opacity:1; /* Fade to opaque */
}

#nav li:hover a{ /* Set styles for top level when dropdown is hovered */
   background:#444444; /* Solid colour fall-back */
   text-decoration:underline;
}

#nav li:hover ul.SubNavSectionList a{ /* Override some top level styles when dropdown is hovered */
   text-decoration:none;
}

#nav li:hover ul.SubNavSectionList li a:hover{ /* Set styles for dropdown when items are hovered */
   background:#333; /* Solid colour fall-back */
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="MainNavBar">         
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
       <a class="MainNavButton" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>    
    <li><!-- Animals Menu -->
       <a class="MainNavButton" href="#">Animals</a><!-- hover over me to show the "animals" menu -->
       <div class="SubNavWrapper"> <!-- This is a wrapper that is absolutly positioned off the screen, until
                                             the "animals" link is hovered over -->                  
          <div class="SubNav"><!-- This is a parent with floating children -->
              <!-- this is a child that floats left -->
              <div class="SubNavSectionWrapper">                        
                <div class="SubNavSectionTitle">Fish</div>
                <ul class="SubNavSectionList">
                   <li><a href="#">Gold Fish</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Barracuda</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
             <!-- this is a child that floats left -->
             <div class="SubNavSectionWrapper">
                <div class="SubNavSectionTitle">Reptiles</div>
                <ul class="SubNavSectionList">
                   <li><a href="#">Lizzards</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Snakes</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Iguanas</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
             
             <!-- this is a child that floats left -->
             <div class="SubNavSectionWrapper">
                <div class="SubNavSectionTitle">Birds</div>
                <ul class="SubNavSectionList">
                   <li><a href="#">Parakeets</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>              
          </div><!-- END SubNav -->
       </div><!-- END SubNavWrapper -->
    </li><!-- END Animals Menu -->
</ul>  
</div> <!-- END Nav Bar -->
```

I got it by forcing the parent to be a fixed width. But the parent needs to vary based on it's children and not be a fixed width.

Comment: so what is happening right now? do they wrap to a new line? did you try `width:auto` on Parent?

Comment: what browser are you testing this in? Im using Chrome and both links you pasted work the same. Birds, reptiles, and fish are next to each other and not on top of the other one.

Comment: I am not a very big fan of the way you are doing this menu :-) the problem is the div being inside the li, go ahead and give the second li a width of 550px then the div starts working like you want. but this is not the solution obviously

Comment: So should I just use divs for the whole thing and get rid of the lists? I've never made a pure css menu before and this was based on a tutorial that suggested using nested lists.

Comment: I can't find any examples of css menus that don't use ul/li...

Comment: Actually it looks like the problem isn't that it's in an li, it's that the li inside is "position:relative". That's what's breaking the layout. But removing position relative causes the absolutely positioned child to be attached to the left of the screen.

Comment: I tried that but didnt offer it as a solution because the reason those LI's need `position:relative` is because the div inside it is `position:absolute` so without the `position:relative`, as you said, it will be on the far left of the page :(

Comment: @Nick, @moe: I think I've fixed this, check the comment on my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Float the `.Parent` `div`s:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/AG3c9/)

**My Test CSS:**

```
.Parent {
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;

    margin: 0 0 16px 0;
    clear: both
}
.Child {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

---

This is what happens when you don't `float: left` the parent div:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/AG3c9/1/

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still insists on stacking the children. (my problem doesn't look like your second "bad" example). It's making the parent div the width of one child div, and placing all three children vertically, one beneath the next. I guess what I want is the way its supposed to work, but my issue is something else entirely? I'll add more code above.

Comment: You're right - the question you asked and your actual problem were entirely different beasts. I fixed your actual problem by making use of `display: inline-block`. I tested my solution in IE7, IE8, and recent versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/AG3c9/16/ - CTRL+F for `/* NEW */` to see the two new parts. I also removed `float: left` from a couple of places.

Comment: Thanks for going above and beyond! I'm going to guess this won't work in IE6, but I'm not sure I care. At some point people just need to update their browsers! Thanks Again!

Comment: Your original code wouldn't work in IE6 anyway because of selectors like this: `#nav li:hover ul.SubNavSectionList a`. IE6 only supports `:hover` on `a` elements. You can work around this if you really want to, but - let's forget about IE6.