# How do I make the width of a container <p> tag match the width of the <span> it contains?

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph that contains a span. The `<p>` tag's width is much wider than the `<span>` it contains, but I would like it to be only as large as its child `<span>`.

```
<p>
    <span>Some text.</span>
</p>
```

I tried `width: auto` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How will the span know when to wrap?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367056/how-do-i-make-a-div-automatically-wide-enough-to-accomodate-its-floating-childre http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102480/how-to-make-a-parent-div-auto-size-to-the-width-of-its-children-divs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747045/css-shrink-a-parent-div-to-fit-one-childs-width-and-constrain-the-width-of-th

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `display:inline-block;` with `p` element.

```
p{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ny37V/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is span is inline element. So his size can't be fixed, and you can't know it directly.

`<p>` is a block. So he have a size and by default is 100%.

So, you can give a style inline to the `<p>`

```
display: inline;
```

or if you want to keep the block advantage :

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution apart from `inline` is to `float` the element

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8AjkL/)

**CSS**

```
p {
    border:1px solid #000;
    float:left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your source

```
p > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```